# width: inherit minus (or plus)

Tags: css, inheritance, height, width, overflow

Is there any method to inherit the width from other class but with **minus (or plus) px** size ?

This is not proper `css` but get the idea:

```
width: inherit - 20px ;
```

Since I'm using inherit width and `10px` padding it goes outside the box for `+ 20px`;

Live example:

```css
.cb {
    width: 340px;
    height: 331px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 41px;
}

.cb .x {
    width: inherit;
    height: 100px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #781111;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cb">
        
    <div class="cb x">
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>                
   </div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why you are using this complecated structure.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can also use `calc` (see **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Pge/2/)**), but I think that the box-sizing approach by kei might be better for your specific case.

The important parts for calc are:

```
position:relative;
width: calc(100% - 18px);
```

Check support for calc [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

Comment: I have just realized how powerful your answer was ! Super ! Thanks !

Comment: Is there a solution to do this to margin? For example `margin-left: value` becomes on hover `margin-left: value + 10px`. With value being 10px or 20px or 30px in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Add `box-sizing:border-box` to `.cb .x`

```css
.cb {
    width: 340px;
    height: 331px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 41px;
}

.cb .x {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: inherit;
    height: 100px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #781111;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="cb">
        
    <div class="cb x">
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>                
   </div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS inheritance does not work that way at all. When an element inherits a property, it always inherits from its parent (not from a class), and the property value of the parent.

To achieve what you are after, you should describe what you really wish to achieve (instead of an assumed technique). You are now using two nested `div` elements, both sharing the same class, which is probably superfluous.